# Auto height vertical scroll bars

Tags: css

I have a div that has a max height. In this divs are two div that contain text.  The first div has a text limit but may be empty or half full so size is not consistent.  The next div has more data but is less important.

The way I want it to work is that when the outer div overflows the second div gets scrollbars but I can't figure out how to do this without specifying a set height but that doesnt work because the other div is varying.

Let me try to show you what I mean.  Take this text:

```
<div id="text-panel">
  <div id="important-text">
    <p>important text</p>
    <p>important text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll-text">
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
    <p>scroll text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
#text-panel{
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  #scroll-text{
    height: auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
  }
}
```

(code pen http://codepen.io/GuerrillaCoder/pen/jPwNav)

If I change scroll-text height to something like 100px then it works but if the important-text is empty then it wont be filling up the full size.

I am not quite sure how to achieve this effect.  Do I have to calculate the height with javascript?  Any libraries that can help?

Comment: You cannot do exactly what you are describing with CSS alone (assuming I understand you). Should the outer div have a fixed height, allocation more space to "scroll-text" when "important text" is short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
#text-panel{
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}

#important-text{
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll-text{
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Such an obvious answer but it eluded me. Thank you for taking time to respond.

Comment: If #important-text height is smaller when 100px,  then #scroll-text won't fill cointener fully

Comment: .. then change max-heigth to height